# Making EF changes using Code First approach

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Not really sure how to articulate my question so I'll do my best and hope it makes sense.

I'm writing an [ASP.NET MVC] app from scratch (bottom up) for the first time, and I'm using Entity Framework with a Code First approach. As I understand it, this means (leaving out the explicit details) I will create my model classes with the appropriate annotations etc., and EF will generate the necessary tables / relationships (obviously assuming I've set everything up correctly in the code) at project runtime.

**First question comes in here -- is my understanding essentially correct, or do I have a fundamental misunderstanding of the workings of code first EF?**

Currently I'm just fleshing out the core features of the app, so I'll only have a few model classes to keep it simple [for the time being]. **My concern is that once I generate the database tables from these models the first time, any further model additions and/or changes I make will break the code and/or database.** Is this the case? Can I freely add new model classes etc. later on after the DB tables have already been generated and expect that EF will sort it all out "on the fly"? Or do I absolutely need to do a comprehensive "end-result" system design before I even generate the tables to begin with?

Comment: Fisrt question - you understand it right. Second question is addressed by EF migrations.

Comment: See [Enabling Migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx#Enabling%20Migrations)

Comment: Regarding your first point: You can choose between having EF figure out the tables / relationships during design time (through the `Add-Migration` and `Update-Database` commands) or during run time (by setting the appropriate database initializer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm writing an [ASP.NET MVC] app from scratch (bottom up) for the
>   first time, and I'm using Entity Framework with a Code First approach.
>   As I understand it, this means (leaving out the explicit details) I
>   will create my model classes with the appropriate annotations etc.,
>   and EF will generate the necessary tables / relationships (obviously
>   assuming I've set everything up correctly in the code) at project
>   runtime.

=>1) You got it!

2) Often, you will want to change the domain model (the entities or the relationship between them), the domain model will evolve during development until it is stable enough. Refer Entity Framework code first migration here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand migrations but I at least addressed any immediate concerns. Thanks